# Indirectly reference remote Javascript URL

Tags: typescript, npm, ecmascript-6, commonjs, rollupjs

We want to use Rollup with Angular 4/Typescript and NPM
We have the following requirement within our company:

- Certain teams create JS libraries which need to be centralized (like a CDN)
- These libraries are behind a remote URL and should not exist locally within the application (the reason is that those libraries change too often)
- The consumer of the library (application) installs a npm package to use the library
- The locally installed npm package contains a Javascript facade file or bundle which puts a remote link to the JS library existing behind a remote URL
- The npm package also contains a Typescript definition file
- The goal is that the consumer doesn't need to add a script tag with an URL (he shouldn't be aware of this)
- The locally installed Javascript file could be bundled together with the application code
- New versions of the library would be backwards compatible if possible

What is the best way to achieve this using Typescript/Javascript/NPM/Rollup?
We would use ES2015 syntax transpiled to commonJS syntax.

Comment: this solution is pretty nice, in all points but I will recommand you to keep simple the think : create a project for your librairy in typescript.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think rollup has something similar to [**webpack dll plugin**](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/), so, my answer may appear unrelated but I think you could assume it as a good starting point and start looking for something similar in rollup.

> **a library living in a CDN**:

1. Create a `DLL` with its corresponding `DLL Reference` which exactly describes how to require the exported modules.
2. Use a self-explaining path and keep it consistent like `https://cdn.mydomain.com/<libraryName>/<version>/<libraryName>.{js,json,d.ts}` (the requester should add `?<cacheBustingUID>` to avoid client caching issues). In addition to the normal versioning, I also suggest you to use a keyword **`latest`** for the `version` field, this to achieve an `always true path` which points to the latest version of the bundle: (`https://cdn.mydomain.com/foo/1.0.0/foo.{js,json,d.ts}`, and `https://cdn.mydomain.com/foo/latest/foo.{js,json,d.ts}`).
3. Resolve all the files and start the dev server (mind that webpack allows to return a promise as a config)

```js
module.exports = env => {
  const libs = ((name, version, exts) => (
    exts.map(ext => `https://cdn.mydomain.com/${name}/${version}/${name}.${ext}`)
  ))('foo', 'latest', ['js', 'd.ts', 'json'])

  return Promise
    .all(libs.map(fetch))
    .then([library, definitions, DLLReference] => {
      // what to do?
      // you can also inject the dynamic paths through `webpackDefinePlugin`
    })
}
```

Comment: Regarding ?<cacheBustingUID>. Would it be a good idea not to have this and to use eTags on the cdn files?

Comment: `etags` are definitely more consistent and the one doesn't exclude the other, so, absolutely keep `eTag` consistent and if some clients needs to force a fresh download, it can also append a query string.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with webpack but as I can read the webpack dll plugin is used to create a vendor js + json manifest. The consumer then needs to put a <script tag referencing the vendor.js and uses webpack dll reference to reference the json file. What is the goal for the consumer application? To be able to create import/require statements? In the setup it would not be improbable that teams would use different module bundlers (like rollup and webpack).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is too complex.
The teams who create those JS libraries should put a bundle behind a URL.
Teams should put that URL and eTag caching should be enabled on those bundles so that users always have the latest version. If a new version of the bundle is deployed the http/1 clients automatically have to redownload the bundle.

Users have to put the URL themselves or a mechanism with json files could be set up where the information resides in json files (like a manifest).

The developers of the application could receive a d.ts file through npm containing all typings of the frameworking library. You won't need to import modules because it's a remote URL. So you don't need to import anything because it's guaranteed that the library is referenced because of a script tag.